# Manage SBT classpathTypes from within SBT plugin

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I'm trying to write an SBT plugin that has a dependency (the plugin itself, during the SBT project definition phase) on JavaCPP, which is published as a `maven-plugin`.

In the `build.sbt` for the plugin, I needed to add `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"` in order for the plugin itself to compile, but when I try to pull it into another project by adding it into that project's `plugins.sbt`, SBT fails to launch for that project () if I don't also add `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"` into the `plugins.sbt` file, e.g.

```
classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"

addSbtPlugin("com.beachape" % "sbt-myplugin" % "1.1")
```

Is there a way for me to manage the classPathTypes from within my plugin so that my projects don't need the classPathTypes line in `plugins.sbt` ? i.e. just

```
addSbtPlugin("com.beachape" % "sbt-myplugin" % "1.1")
```

Comment: Wow, this is annoying... I wonder if the only way to fix that is by publishing a non-plugin artifact for JavaCPP?